# Simple Linq to Xml Queries setting Properties with Elements (instead of IEnumerable)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to write a simple Linq to Xml query to extract the `serverOpen` and `onlinePlayers` values into my class which has two properties `ServerStatus` and `Players` respectively.

The xml I'm dealing with is of this simple form:

```
<eveapi version="2">
   <currentTime>2013-02-10 05:27:33</currentTime>
   <result>
     <serverOpen>True</serverOpen>
     <onlinePlayers>32723</onlinePlayers>
   </result>
   <cachedUntil>2013-02-10 05:28:39</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

I feel like this should be a very trivial solution.  There is only ever one result in the XML and I want to be able to query it out very simply.

I've tried things like (`Results` is my xml in a XDocument):

```
var result = Results.Elements().Elements().First(); //successfully gets result
ServerStatus = result.Element("serverOpen").Value;  //this doesn't work
                       //null reference exception with .Value
```

Also a few other queries that all return IEnumerables and I have never been able to successfully extract the values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a bit easier to use xpath here instead, particularly if there isn't a result.

```
var serverStatus = (bool?)doc.XPathSelectElement("/eveapi/result/serverOpen");
var onlinePlayers = (int?)doc.XPathSelectElement("/eveapi/result/onlinePlayers");
```

Comment: I did not know about xpath.  I figured out how to do it with linq, but this looks much more like what I would like to do in this situation.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought the same thing, at first sight. Way to go XPath!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to use an overlooked XDocument method `Single()` to get just the single `result` XElement.  Then use `Element()` to extract the correct XElements from the `result` XElement.

```
var result = Results.Descendants("result").Single();
ServerStatus = result.Element("serverOpen").Value;
```

If there is a better way or another flashy way please submit your own suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but if I understand Linq correctly, you already have your object.
Instead of:

```
ServerStatus = result.Element("serverOpen").Value;
```

do:

```
ServerStatus = result.Value;
```

Hope this helps.